# What's a nice word to say "we considered your input and will not go forward with it"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm in charge of a database where engineers can voice their concerns. We can close out tickets with the following resolutions:

- "Mitigated" - we actively worked to fix the concern
- "Accepted" - we have to accept the fact that the concern is valid and we won't/can't do anything about it
- "Invalid" - this isn't a concern
- "Duplicate" - this concern was already covered.

Up to this point, things that aren't a concern have been closed as "invalid" because they're not a concern. But it was pointed out to me that if an engineer keeps having concerns and they keep getting closed as "invalid", they might not feel great and stop sharing their concerns. But an "invalid" disposition may be the result of something obvious OR it was something that was seriously considered and decided that the concern isn't valid.

Is there a nicer way, with 1-2 words, to communicate to our engineers that we considered their thoughts and decided that the concern isn't valid?

Comment: "SEP" (Someone Else's Problem)  ;-)

Comment: "Request declined", "user error", "technical improvement request", "It's not a bug, it's a feature", "The software specification has been frozen", "the software has already been shipped", "the software is at end-of-life", etc. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me "Accepted" covers the area currently labeled as "Invalid", but if you really want to make a distinction between "we won't/can't do anything about it" and "we will not do anything about it," I suggest the word "Noted!" (or "Noted! Thank you!" or "Your reported is noted.")

Answer (score 1):

Although it has a somewhat negative connotation, **rejected** is a concise description of this status for a change request.

But if it's not an improvement request, but a bug report, and you've decided that the bug isn't serious enough to warrant fixing, psosuna's **wontfix** seems appropriate.

You could also just keep the bug report open. Maybe eventually you'll decide that it's worth fixing. You could have an **onhold** status to indicate its low priority.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because I'm a bugzilla user in a few places, but the tags ***wontfix*** and ***worksforme*** are two that I think convey this a little better than just "invalid".

The tag ***wontfix*** is generally used when an issue is a known issue, but either fixing that issue breaks something larger, or fixing the issue takes an inordinate amount of time/effort/resources, to the point that it is more efficient and resourceful to proceed with the known issue and its current handling.

The tag ***worksforme*** is generally used when trying to express user error in a way that is not demonizing. It hints at a possible environment issue that is causing something to not come up properly, hence, "it works for me, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you."